# Parse this data with PHP

Tags: php, html, parsing, loops

Going to this webstie:

```
http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29
```

Yields this result:

```
{"success":true,"lowest_price":"5,59&#8364; ","volume":"5,688","median_price":"5,92&#8364; "}
```

The result is updated every time the page is refreshed. Using PHP, how would I be able to save the result line and split it up in my code I can use it for other things? Would it be viable/possible to do this about 3000-5000 times from a loop in my code, or would it be too much and crash it? I won't be using all the data from it in my code, just saving it into a database and moving to the next result.

Comment: [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) is your friend

Comment: Why are people down voting my question? This is supposed to be a place where people can learn, not be ridiculed for posting legitimate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is JSON and can be parsed with [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29');
$json = json_decode($data);
echo $json->volume;
```

As far as looping... why? You would simply load the page 3000+ times in a row. What would be the benefit of that? Perhaps you should consider a cron job instead, which could fetch the data at regular intervals (and not spam the Steam servers)

Comment: Thank you, that works. Regards to the looping part, I should have specified that the 3000+ times would all be for edited links, which would all display different data, but in the same format. I was planing on running a cron job, which would loop through the 3000+ links to get all the data, every day or hour, that's what I really wanted to know, whether that would be too much or inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is in JSON format.

So:

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29');

json_decode($content);
```

Should work correctly